# wordpress 500 error in admin panel

Tags: wordpress

in admin page every requests has one error on Network view (Firefox Firebug). For example, on page **wp-admin/plugins.php**  i have error:

```
GET  // type
plugins.php // url
500 Internal Server Error // status
[my domain name]
59,6 KB // response size
```

In response has correct html-code and in HTML tab of response i can see this page as it should be (with opened admin-sidebar etc.)

screenshot: http://gyazo.com/d3e41ff2dcc2d04882dadcb9320e0707.png

So, correct response exists, but request marked as 500 error.

Because of this i can not fully use admin panel and switch between html-editor/source.

Server configuration wan not changed (home server, Nginx + Apache)

How can i fix it?

Comment: Check the error logs for details on the error. Or, define [WP_DEBUG](http://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG) in your wp-config file so the error shows on screen. Identifying the problem is half way to solving it :)

Comment: Also, disable all plugins, switch to TweentyEleven and see if the problem persists.